# Need to check that my current directory is in a certain sub-directory

Tags: bash

I am writing a script to help me organize my classes.

I want to be able to run a command such as

```
class econ -h
```

to go to the directory for my econ class, then to the sub-directory for homework (which is already created inside each class directory). I have that working perfectly, but I want to expand my program to allow simply:

```
class -h
```

from /home/USER/School/Semester-Fall/Econ/, what would I need to do to check that path and compare it to a default of let's say: /home/USER/School/Semester-Fall/

Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough or you need more information, thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to get `class -h` to do? Use the `homework` directory of the current directory? Of some default directory? Something else?

Comment: Can you use `${PWD}` ?

Comment: Yes, ideally `class -h` would simply go to the homework directory of the class that I am currently in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Need to check that my current directory is in a certain sub-directory"*

For convenience, let's define the "certain subdirectory" as `default`:

```
default="/home/USER/School/Semester-Fall/"
```

Now, to check to see if the current directory is under the directory defined by `$default`, use:

```
[ "${PWD#$default}" != "$PWD" ] && echo "Yes, we are under default"
```

or:

```
if [ "${PWD#$default}" != "$PWD" ]
then
    echo "Yes, we are under default"
else
    echo "No, we are not"
fi
```

Under bash, `$PWD` is the current working directory.

`${PWD#$default}` is an example of *prefix removal*.  If the current working directory starts with the value of `$default`, then `$default` is removed.

If it is true that `"${PWD#$default}" != "$PWD"`, then we know that `$PWD` starts with `$default` and, therefore, that the current working directory is under `$default`.

For this to work reliably, `$default` should end with a `/`.

#### Examples illustrating prefix removal

```
$ s=/home/USER/School/Semester-Fall/Econ/
$ echo "${s#/ho}"
me/USER/School/Semester-Fall/Econ/
$ echo "${s#/home/USER/School/Semester-Fall/}"
Econ/
$ echo "${s#/home/OtherUser/School/Semester-Fall/}"
/home/USER/School/Semester-Fall/Econ/
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you also for explaining it all.